# How can i implement custom logger which will print the values like @Logging

Tags: java

I have a code where it contains many methods, it was written such that no loggers are added, later on we have decided to add the loggers to track bugs, but ended up with huge amount of data. is there a way to automate such that all the data gets printed in logs like @Loggable in sprint boot.

```java
public class Test10 {

    @Loggable
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> li = new ArrayList<>();
        li.add("1");
        li.add("2");
        li.add("3");
        li.add("4");
        addMore1(li);
        li.forEach(e -> {System.out.println(e);});
        System.out.println(li);
    }

    @Loggable
    private static void addMore1(List<String> li) {
        li.add("5");
        li.add("6");
        li.add("7");
        li.add("8");
        addMore2(li);
        System.out.println(li);
    }

    @Loggable
    private static void addMore2(List<String> li) {

        li.add("9");
        li.add("10");
        li.add("11");
        li.add("12");
        System.out.println(li);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to print the values inside a method with Loggable annotation?

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot, you could take advantage of AOP (aspect-oriented programming), to intercept methods with the `@Loggable` annotation and log their parameters.

The most trivial example follows, see more in the documentation on [spring-aop](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop)

Annotation:

```java
package com.example;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface Loggable {
}
```

Aspect:

```java
package com.example;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before(value = "@annotation(com.example.Loggable)")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        if (joinPoint.getArgs() != null) {
            for (Object arg : joinPoint.getArgs()) {
                System.out.println(arg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to replace logging to `System.out` with a proper logger, add logging of method names and provide some pretty-printing for specific argument types.